# MYSQL - Generate Report with Filled Gaps

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

How would I generate a report with filled gaps that shows zero results for date as well as time slots?

Here's what I have so far that works for DATE :

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE,
       IFNULL(COUNT(digital_lead.id),0) AS leads
FROM digital_lead RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(digital_lead.received) = calendar.datefield)
WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE('2014-09-01')) FROM digital_lead) AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(received)) FROM digital_lead))
GROUP BY DATE
```

Which produces the following table:

```
 DATE         LEADS 
'2014-11-08', '0'
'2014-11-09', '0'
'2014-11-10', '0'
'2014-11-11', '0'
'2014-11-12', '524'
'2014-11-13', '934'
'2014-11-14', '524'
```

So this produces results for every day even those that are not accounted for by the `TIMESTAMP` field `received`.

The `received` field is a `TIMESTAMP` field in the format of 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.

I would like to be able to generate a similar report showing the breakdown by DATE and TIME - showing the zero results for both DATE and TIME slots.

I have created a utility table named `clock`containing all of the hours of the day.

See SQL fiddle for scehema details:

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/634f3/1)

I was thinking I could join the `clock` table onto `digital_lead` as I have done with `calendar`, however, this produces a single row with one time and date 2014-11-13 00:00:00.

Can anybody provide a solution?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify I would like to JOIN the clock table to the MYSQL statment given above and create the following output :

```
     DATE           HOURS   LEADS
    2014-11-06      00:00:00    0'
                    01:00:00    0'
                    02:00:00    0'
                    03:00:00    4

    2014-11-07      00:00:00    0'
                    01:00:00    2
                    02:00:00    1
```

The dates for the calendar table are generated using the following PROCEDURE:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_calendar(start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
BEGIN
  DECLARE crt_date DATE;
  SET crt_date=start_date;
  WHILE crt_date < end_date DO
    INSERT INTO calendar VALUES(crt_date);
    SET crt_date = ADDDATE(crt_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  END WHILE;
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Which is called as follows `CALL fill_calendar('2008-01-01', '2011-12-31');`

Comment: How do you join `clock` table ?

Comment: @a1ex07 - see edit above. Is this clearer?

Comment: Hooray for RIGHT JOIN

Comment: There's not a lot in calendar. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Strawberry - my mistake! See edit above, the dates are generated with a PROCEDURE.

Comment: OK - I'm possibly being a bit dim. You have a row with various datetime values from 2014-11-12 and somehow you want to generate dates 11-06 and 11-07 from that !?!?

Comment: I would like to generate a report by date and timeslot (hours) which shows empty results. So if between yesterday and today there were no results between 1:00am and 3:00am - then I would like zero return instead of missing results in the output.